# Adding a LUKS-encrypted OS to Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, luks

I recently installed Debian (using an encrypted LVM) onto an NVMe drive. The /boot and EFI partitions are of course not encrypted. However, I discovered that my old, rickety motherboard I'm using doesn't allow booting to NVMe for whatever reason, although I still do have access to the drive (including the /boot partition) from my Ubuntu install on a separate disk. I was wondering how I could go about adding the newly installed operating system to Grub (on the same disk as Ubuntu) so that I may boot from it?

**TL;DR**

I have these two drives:

- NVMe

  - `EFI` Partition
  - `/boot`
  - LUKS volume containing an LVM Debian install
  - ***Cannot be booted-to by motherboard*** because it is old(er)
- SSD

  - `EFI` Partition
  - Ubuntu install with `/boot` included

Is there a way I can add the LUKS-encrypted Debian OS to my Grub on the Ubuntu SSD?

Comment: Was LUKS partition decrypted when you were recreating grub-configuration? I would expect os-prober would find the other OS automatically if the LUKS volume is open.  By the way, /boot partitions can be encrypted just fine. Only EFI partition has to be unencrypted.

Comment: os-prober did indeed find it, but choosing that boot option presents me with the errors of `could not find disk: ...` and `could not find vmlinuz`, etc. I guess this may be more of how do I set grub to ask me for the password for that drive so I can decrypt it?

Comment: Maybe GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y in /etc/default/grub would help? Although most likely it is more complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. Looks like I might just have to wait till I upgrade the whole PC :( Oh well.